# Android: how to deny access to the components of my application from other applications?

Tags: android

Iwant to know how to deny access to the components of my application from other applications

Comment: let me know if it helps u mate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default android os don't allow other app to access your component. So you don't need to worry about it. You have to change permission in case you want to allow other app to access your component.